# Android, SQL Join Tables

Tags: android, sql

I want to know if it is possible to Join two tables, the Playlist Table has a list of id's separated with a comma to the Songs table containing the corresponding id, So as to end up with a Cursor containing all of the Songs in the Playlist, also how to do this using a content Provider in Android

Playlist Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|       Title         |        Ids       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Playlist 1      | 12, 34, 53, 91   |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Playlist 2      | 7, 19, 25, 81, 9 |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     Playlist 3      |    4, 91, 34     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Song Table

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          Id         |      Artist      |       Track      |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          12         | Michael Jackson  |        Bad       |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          19         |       Sia        |    Chandelier    |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          34         | Smashing Pumpkins|      Tonight     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: You can create a view.

Comment: Fix your data structure!  You should not be storing lists of numerical ids as comma-delimited strings.  That is simply wrong when using a SQL database.

Comment: Thanks Gordon I have read a few posts and i understand i am violating the conditions of first Normal Form i.e.                                                                        
A database is in first normal form if it satisfies the following conditions:

Contains only atomic values
There are no repeating groups. Would a better approach to have the same title in the Playlist Table for each individual id